# linux3/gcc46: "-fnon-call-exceptions", which signals are trapping instructions?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, glibc

(Environment: gcc/g++ 4.6.1 in -std=gnu++0x mode on Linux 3.0 / x86_64...)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SegmentationFault {};

void ThrowSegmentationFault(int)
{
    throw SegmentationFault();
}

void ohno(char* x)
{
    *x = 42;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, ThrowSegmentationFault);

    try
    {
        ohno(0);
    }
    catch (const SegmentationFault&)
    {
        cout << "success" << endl;
    }
}
```

By compiling the above with the *-fnon-call-exceptions* flag, it allows the *SIGSEGV* signal handler to throw an exception, and when run it will print "success". The documentation of the *-fnon-call-exceptions* gcc flag reads as follows:

> Generate code that allows trapping instructions to throw
>   exceptions. Note that this requires platform-specific runtime support
>   that does not exist everywhere. Moreover, it only allows trapping
>   instructions to throw exceptions, i.e. memory references or floating
>   point instructions. It does not allow exceptions to be thrown from
>   arbitrary signal handlers such as SIGALRM.

My question is which of the signals are trapping instructions and which are not?

```
#define SIGHUP           1
#define SIGINT           2
#define SIGQUIT          3
#define SIGILL           4
#define SIGTRAP          5
#define SIGABRT          6
#define SIGIOT           6
#define SIGBUS           7
#define SIGFPE           8
#define SIGKILL          9
#define SIGUSR1         10
#define SIGSEGV         11
#define SIGUSR2         12
#define SIGPIPE         13
#define SIGALRM         14
#define SIGTERM         15
#define SIGSTKFLT       16
#define SIGCHLD         17
#define SIGCONT         18
#define SIGSTOP         19
#define SIGTSTP         20
#define SIGTTIN         21
#define SIGTTOU         22
#define SIGURG          23
#define SIGXCPU         24
#define SIGXFSZ         25
#define SIGVTALRM       26
#define SIGPROF         27
#define SIGWINCH        28
#define SIGIO           29
#define SIGPOLL         SIGIO
/*
#define SIGLOST         29
*/
#define SIGPWR          30
#define SIGSYS          31
#define SIGUNUSED       31
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SIGILL, SIGTRAP, SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGSEGV, SIGSTKFLT are the most probable synchronous signals (i.e., generated by hardware as consequence of an instruction trying to do something invalid).