# How to produce codes that always trigger signal SIGFPE (div by zero)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, optimization, divide-by-zero, sigfpe

I need to code a unit-test that should always trigger a divided by zero signal (SIGFPE), so I can test and compare what would happen with/without my signal catching module.

My Linux signal catching/resuming module has been developed, and worked as expecting. When I'm coding the unit-test for the module, I encounter a small trouble.

These are the UT codes (by means of GTest):

```
int do_div_by_0() {
    int j = 0;
    return 123 / j; /* During release-building, this div-op would be optimized out,
                       although it would be not when debug-building! */
};

TEST_F( SignalsHandling_F, divByZeroDying ) {
   ASSERT_EXIT( {
      do_div_by_0();
      
      // never should go here!
      exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );

   }, KilledBySignal( SIGFPE ), "" );
};
```

If all codes are built in Debug mode, there's no problem. But the division operation would be optimized out in Release mode, as a result the SIGFPE signal would Never be triggered!

To keep the consistency between product codes and testing codes, I must build them all in release mode when I release my product.

How to compose a piece of code that always trigger the signal SIGFPE?

I don't want to use raise() function if a more "actual" method exists, because I want to actually trigger out SIGFPE signal.

Comment: Did you try simply declaring `j` in global scope? The compiler can't prove that `j`,  even though it's initialized by 0, couldn't possibly be modified in another translation unit.

Comment: Or maybe using `volatile` qualifier.

Comment: Usually to avoid this sort of problem, you need to put some of your testing code in different compilation units so that the compiler cannot optimize between them.  Even then you can get problems if you enable link-time optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that ChrisDodd's answer is the most precise one. I.e. **the return value of do_div_by_0 is ignored, so that the compiler optimizes out the division operation**.

We need to use the return value when we call do_div_by_0, like follows:

```
TEST_F( SignalsHandling_F, divByZeroDying ) {
   ASSERT_EXIT( {
      std::cerr << do_div_by_0();
      
      // never should go here!
      exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );

   }, KilledBySignal( SIGFPE ), "" );
};
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

```
int do_div_by_0() {
   int j = 0;
   FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/foobar",  "r");
   if (f) {
     fscanf(f, "%d", &j);
     fclose(f);
   };
   return 123 / j; /* During release-buidling, this div-op would be optimized out,
                   although it would be not when debug-building! */
};
```

could be a solution. Current [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers (so [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in September 2020) are not able to figure out the content of file `/tmp/foobar` at runtime (even when strongly optimizing with e.g. `gcc -O3 -Wall`).

Of course, a serious test case would involve some shell script filling that `/tmp/foobar` and using some [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) variable for the file name. See also [mktemp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html) to be used in your testing shell script.

Comment: The problem is likely that do_div_by_0 is getting inlined, and then the division is being eliminated because the return value is ignored, which is not affected by the additional code here...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yeap! You got it! I tried it out according to your hint! It just because that the result of the func be ignored, so gcc always optimize out the division code! if I use the result of the func, it would not be optimized out anyway!

Comment: @ChrisDodd Would you please add a formal answer? I think I should accept your answer.